# Keras softmax layer returns one-hot encoded array

Tags: keras, loss-function, one-hot-encoding, softmax

I am using a simple net for classification but the output of the predict is one-hot encoded. I checked inside the loss function and the actual output is correct.

```
ip = Input(shape=(padding_size, n_features))   
x = LSTM(50, activation='relu')(ip)
x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
out = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x) 
model = Model(ip, out)
```

I am using a custom loss function. The first three items of y_true are the one-hot encoding of the label, the remaining three are values used inside the function.

```
def odds_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    print(y_pred) #see below
    print(y_true) #see below
    
    true_1 = y_true[:, 0:1]
    true_2 = y_true[:, 1:2]
    true_3 = y_true[:, 2:3]
    feature_a = y_true[:, 3:4]
    feature_b = y_true[:, 4:5]
    feature_c = y_true[:, 5:6]

    vector = K.concatenate([
        true_1 * (feature_a - 0.3),
        true_2 * (feature_b - 3.3) + K.log(feature_b - 1),
        true_3 * (feature_c - 2.8)
    ], axis = 1)

    return -1 * K.mean(K.sum(vector * y_pred, axis=1))
```

The output of those print, for a batch of four elements is:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[0.33180252 0.3375508  0.3306467 ]
 [0.3335974  0.3334575  0.33294514]
 [0.33349878 0.333613   0.33288828]
 [0.3354906  0.3324541  0.33205533]], shape=(4, 3), 
dtype=float32)

tf.Tensor(
[[1.  0.  0.  1.467  3.252  5.312]
 [0.  1.  0.  1.251  2.851  4.665]
 [0.  1.  0.  1.642  2.319  5.133]
 [0.  0.  1.  1.635  1.996  3.985]], shape=(4, 3), 
dtype=float32)
```

As expected, at this stage it's just random guessing. However, if I execute the predict with some test data I only get one hot encoded arrays, all the same:

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)

[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1.]]
```

I manually checked the operations inside the loss function, the returned value is as expected. Why am I not getting the same output as inside the loss function?